# Jquery remove button stops working after one click

Tags: jquery, button

I have a form which allows users to dynamically add fields.  Every field after the first has a "remove" button added to it.
The following is in the document.ready

```
var new_button =$('<div class="form-actions"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove pull-right">Remove</button></div>').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.field_group').remove();
    });
```

I then append the button to the new group of fields when they are created like this

```
$('#more_fields').click(function(){
    $('.field_group:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.field_group:last');
        var last = $('.field_group:last');
        last.append(new_button);
 );
```

My goal is to remove the entire ".field_group" that surrounds the button each time it is clicked.  However, this only works once.  Oddly enough if I have the button do something else like change the field group background color it works all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to append a copy of the button.

`last.append(new_button.clone(true));`

Comment: When I try this, the new button ceases to function entirely

Comment: You have to clone with dataAndEvents (I've updated the code). Since you are using .clone elsewhere, I assumed you know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

For a more modular approach which doesn't involve loads of HTML, you could change `new_button` to the following :

```
var new_button = $("<div/>", {
    "class": "form-actions"
}).append($("<button/>", {
    "class": "btn btn-primary remove pull-right",
    "text": "Remove"
})).on("click", "button", function () {
     $(this).parents('.field_group').remove();
});
```

and as Darhazer mentioned, you must use `clone(true)`.

```
$('#more_fields').click(function(){
    $('.field_group:first').clone(true).insertAfter('.field_group:last');
        var last = $('.field_group:last');
        last.append(new_button.clone(true));

});
```